# Jquery add Class when audio is playing remove class when it is not

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I am working on a master control panel for an audio player I am developing.

For the most part it is working fine except the bottom play button will toggle out of sync if I play another song while a track is already playing:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jeffd/2fjnmdkb/6/

```
$(".play").on('click', function () {
     var key = $(this).attr('key');
     EvalSound(this, key);
     var this_play = $(this);
     $(".play").each(function () {
         if ($(this)[0] != this_play[0]) {
             $(this).removeClass("pause");
         }
     });
     $(".playerbottom").toggleClass("pausebottom");
     $(this).toggleClass("pause");
 });
 var thissound = new Audio();
 var currentKey;
 function EvalSound(el, key) {
     thissound.addEventListener('ended', function () {
         // done playing
         $(el).removeClass("pause");
         $(".playerbottom").removeClass("pausebottom");
     });
     if (currentKey !== key) thissound.src = "http://99centbeats.com/1e4cb5f584d055a0992385c1b2155786/" + key + ".mp3";
     currentKey = key;
     if (thissound.paused) thissound.play();
     else thissound.pause();
     //thissound.currentTime = 0;
     currentPlayer = thissound;
 }
$(".volume_slider").slider({
    value  : 75,
    step   : 1,
    range  : 'min',
    min    : 0,
    max    : 100,
    slide  : function(){
        var value = $(".volume_slider").slider("value");
        thissound.volume = (value / 100);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing your `play` event to [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/2fjnmdkb/8/):

```
$(".play").on('click', function () {
     var key = $(this).attr('key');
     EvalSound(this, key);
     $(".play").not(this).removeClass("pause");     
     $(this).toggleClass("pause");
     $(this).hasClass("pause") ? $(".playerbottom").addClass("pausebottom") : $(".playerbottom").removeClass("pausebottom");
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
$(".play").on('click', function () {
     var key = $(this).attr('key');
     var this_play = $(this);
     $(".play").each(function () {
         if ($(this)[0] != this_play[0]) {
             $(this).removeClass("pause");
         }
     });
     $(this).toggleClass("pause");
     var player_bottom = $(".playerbottom");
     if (currentKey == key || !player_bottom.hasClass('pausebottom')) {
         player_bottom.toggleClass("pausebottom");
     }
     EvalSound(this, key);
 });
```

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2fjnmdkb/9/)